# Is there a way to create an ArrayList under certain circumstances?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm sorry if the question is phrased weirdly, but I wasn't quite sure how to fit it into the title space. I'm making a mini messaging program in which users create and log into accounts and send and receive messages. Is there a way to create an ArrayList of the user's messages when they create an account? All of the usernames are in another ArrayList, so maybe it can create one for every addition? I have the passwords and usernames in two different lists linked by position, so that could work too if it's even possible.

PS - I also need to be able to pull out and match the ArrayList to usernames, but that will come later.

I can clarify in the comments and show my code if you need it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a list of anything. Question needs to be specific if there is anything you're struggling with.

Comment: The formal answer is "yes", you can do this, but ultimately it depends on how your code is structured.  Probably not the most informative or interesting answer you could get on this subject matter, if you asked me...

Comment: you shouldn't store linked data in separate data structures like that. It's difficult to keep them in sync. Create a `User` class with `username` and `password` fields, then store all the `User` objects in *one* list. You can also add a `messages` field and whatever else a user needs.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a data structure to store a list of messages per user. You can use a `Map<User, List<Message>` for this. When loading/adding a `User`, you can create an empty `ArrayList<Message>` and put it into the map for later use.

```java
// Create map.
Map<User, List<Message>> userMessageMap = new HashMap<>();

// Insert new list for new user.
userMessageMap.put(user, new ArrayList<>());

// Insert message for existing user.
userMessageMap.get(user).add(message);

// Get all messages for an existing user.
List<Message> messages = userMessageMap.get(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Pieter12345](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848890/642706) is correct and smart.

Here is a table graphic I made to assist you in choosing an implementation of `Map` from among those bundled with Java. All of these support the operations seen in that other Answer.

Third-parties produce may produce `Map` implementations as well, such as *Eclipse Collections* or *Google Guava*.

[image]

Comment: Useful addition. For choosing the proper implementation, the runtime (and possibly space) complexity should also be considered though. These can be found in a nice table here: https://gist.github.com/psayre23/c30a821239f4818b0709
EDIT: I just noticed that this table isn't complete for maps, that's unfortunate.